# Customize a CSS/HTML circular menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a circular menu on the web that I'm struggling to customize since I don't know much about jQuery.

I made this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zv5dr670/4/

If you click to the big blue button, it's working fine and all items are toggling and vanishing.

What I want is to make work this button with an other button ( click2 button here).

```
 <button class ="mycbutton">Click2</button>
```

It's almost working but the Menu9 is still here while the other items are gone.

Any advice ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
$('.mycbutton').click(function(e) {
    toggleOptions($(this).prev('.selector'));
});
```

cause your .mycbutton button not a parent of .selector so you need to use `.prev()`

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zv5dr670/8/)